# Updating an Excel Cell Using PLSQL

Tags: excel, plsql, plsql-package

Is there a way we can update an existing Excel file using only PLSQL codes? I saw a working PLSQL code that can create an excel file and write a text into a cell I specified, as well as a PLSQL code that can read an existing excel file and return the text in the cell I specified. But haven't found any code that will update the text in the cell I specified in an existing Excel file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you refer to XLSX format, there are Anton Scheffer's (good old) [AS_XLSX and AS_READ_XLSX packages](https://www.google.com/search?q=as_read_xlsx%20as_xlsx).